# How to become a cricket umpire for junior level

Tags: cricket

I am 17 years old and I want to be able to umpire at a junior level (primary school). I want to firstly know if it is possible and if so, how do I become one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user appears to be job searching.

Comment: This is nothing like a job search - the OP is asking how to become involved in officiating at a junior level. It's a good question, and a valid one!

Comment: I agree with @TrueDub here - this would seem to me to part of being a ["participant" in a sport](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: thank you for seeing this from my side TrueDub and Philip Kendall. I am a very active participant in this sport and have been since I was able to stand. I am simply trying to find out more about furthering my career in the sport. as I said im only 17 years old and I am still in school so it is not possible for me to be working at this given time.

Comment: Everyone: please be nice to each other. That is one of the core behaviors we expect from *everyone* on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely possible to do so, we have plenty of umpires here in the UK standing in cricket up to and including men's league games.  Your best course of action is to speak to your local cricket association who would be able to tell you when and where the next umpires course is.  If you are in the UK you can also go to https://www.ecb.co.uk/be-involved/officials/find-a-course. Good luck.